# Angular 8 Videojs is not working on mobile browser (in Android and also iOs)

Tags: angular, http-live-streaming, video.js

I am creating an application on Angular 8, am using videojs HLS stream. It is working on Desktop browsers, but the video is not playing on mobile browsers. I did some R&D but found nothing useful on how to make videojs HLS to play on mobile device.

```js
import videojs from 'video.js';
declare var require: any;
require('videojs-contrib-quality-levels');
require('videojs-hls-quality-selector');

const options = {
      'sources': [{
        'src': this.url,
        'type': 'application/x-mpegURL'
      }
      ],      
    };
    
    const policyQueryparam = this.queryparam;
    
    videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function(options)
    {
        options.uri = options.uri+'?'+policyQueryparam;
        console.log(options);
        return options;
    };
    
    this.player = videojs('my_promo_video_1', options, function onPlayerReady() 
    {

    const options = {
          'sources': [{
            'src': this.url,
            'type': 'application/x-mpegURL'
          }
          ],      
        };
        
        const policyQueryparam = this.queryparam;
        
        videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function(options)
        {
            options.uri = options.uri+'?'+policyQueryparam;
            console.log(options);
            return options;
        };
        
        this.player = videojs('my_promo_video_1', options, function onPlayerReady() 
        {
          console.log('Player ready');
          var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();
          myPlayer.hlsQualitySelector();
        });


      console.log('Player ready');
      var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();
      myPlayer.hlsQualitySelector();
    });
```